# Delete a line in Visual Studio without copying it?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio, editing

There is the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to delete a line, but I want to delete the line without modifying what is in the clipboard.

Is there some way to configure it or another shortcut?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Because `Del` on highlighted lines works for Visual Studio 2008. I wouldn't have posted my answer if I hadn't tested it first.

Comment: Also what keyboard mapping scheme are you using?

Comment: @T. Kaltnekar - he should have explained that in the question or as a comment on the answer, we're not all mind readers!

Comment: Well, he did state he's looking for a shortcut which would suggest a key combination. I usually just go to start of line, pres Shift+Down then Del. Didn't even know there's a combo for directly deleting a line. For most simple things I don't use special shortcuts since they usually work in one editor and not in another.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

By default, if you are using the C# default profile, you can delete a line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

You can customize this using Tools->Customize.  Select "Keyboard".  Look for the command **Edit.LineDelete** to assign it to whichever keyboard shortcut you like.

Comment: +1 for pointing out where you can find a key combo or add new one.

Comment: This setting is under Tools>Options as mentioned [below](http://superuser.com/questions/194004/delete-a-line-in-visual-studio-without-copying-it/614442#614442)

Comment: And more importantly, `CTRL+SHIFT+L` doesn't copy the line to the buffer (`SHIFT + Del` is assigned to `CUT` by default).  So if you re-assign `SHIFT + Del` as the short-cut for `Edit.LineDelete` then you can have that nice shortcut with the nasty side-effect.  Nice one, thanks!

Comment: What is different between `CTRL+L` and `CTRL+SHIFT+L`?

Comment: mgae2m - CTRL+L is Edit.LineCut while CTRL+SHIFT+L is Edit.LineDelete

Answer (score 96):

If you got here looking for an answer for Visual Studio **Code** the default shortcut is:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for Windows

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for MacOS

However, you can change on `File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts`

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+delete",
    "command": "editor.action.deleteLines",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

For Visual Studio answer see [@heavyd's answer](https://superuser.com/a/194006/48044)

Comment: `ctrl` + `shift` + `K` works for me on Linux.

Answer (score 14):

```
Ctrl + Shift + K
```

will work fine for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this. It has already been posited as an answer & has one comment underneath... "No it's not."

Answer (score 4):

Go to tools -> options. Tab Environment -> subtab Keyboard.

Select Edit.LineDelete. Assign a shortcut. Thats it.
I use Alt + D.

Answer (score 2):

**Default Shortcut Key in VS Code is :** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Actually it works just fine on Windows 10 with Visual Studio Code 1.32.3.

Comment: Also worked for me in W10

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home), which are made by Microsoft, as an extension.

The feature that you might get some use out of is Triple Click, which highlights an entire line when you triple click it.  Then you can simply use the Delete key.

Comment: Whaaat? Triple click... interesting idea. I need to try this.

Comment: this answer is outdated. Let's downvote it

Answer (score 1):

The [Shortcuts WinForms Control](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/shortcut.shtml) supports the modifier keys, multiple keys shortcuts, and shortcuts without modifier keys to build a keyboard trigger action, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> with any other keys to trigger a specific action for their Windows applications.

Answer (score 0):

This combination will only delete the line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Source: [Cut or Delete the Current Line](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/04/cut-or-delete-the-current-line-vstipedit0038.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am quite late in the party, but, here is a list of Shortcut keys for Visual Studio: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyush/archive/2007/03/16/useful-visual-studio-shortcut-keys.aspx

Comment: Can you add in the relevant parts of the link into your answer? We ask this to help the OP out, so they will not have to search through information that may not pertain to them. This is also to preserve the relevant information in case the hosting site goes down. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I realized 4 years later too that this should a comment :D, deleting it

Answer (score 0):

If you often find yourself copying blank lines to the clipboard and erasing the previous clipboard contents, try navigating to Tools->Options->Text Editor->[All Languages or your favorite language]->General and unchecking “Apply Cut or Copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection.”

Answer (score -1):

Or, the old fashioned way (for me it is a habit and I even had to think what was the combination :) ):

1. Go to the line you want to delete
2. Press 'Home'
3. Then 'Shift' + 'End'
4. Then 'Del'
5. and again 'Del'

Works in most text editors :)

Comment: Not what I asked.

Comment: Yes, of course this works.  But it is too slow! :)

Comment: Same thing, but one key less: go to line, `Home`, `Shift`+`Down`, `Del` ;)

Comment: Old school boy :)

Comment: You must be patient java, assembler programmist or linux user. .NET programists don't like such unproductive, time-wasting methods ;)

Answer (score -1):

It seems I'm risking a downvote for not providing a single-keystroke solution, but I want to share my solution anyway:

```
HOME, SHIFT + ARROW-DOWN (repeat for multiple lines), DEL
```

It's quick and has the added advantage that works in other editors as well.

Comment: I did get down-voted for suggesting this very solution.

Comment: My question is not how to delete a line in a text-editor. It is about a shortcut on Visual Studio to delete a line.

Comment: @BrunoLM: my solution works in Visual Studio

Comment: see @T. Kaltnekar's comment on the question

Comment: Not what I asked.

Comment: This is not keyboard shortcut, this is another "how to play on the piano" answer ;)